# How do I solve an error in php related to sessions?

Tags: php, session

I keep getting this error on the pages on my site where I write: session_start();.  An example and the error I get are below.

```
<?php
include("header.php");

  // The shopping cart needs sessions, so start one
  session_start();
```

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/c/a/s/cashme/html/buylooper/viewcart.php:5) in /home/content/c/a/s/cashme/html/buylooper/viewcart.php on line 9

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `session_start()` above the `include("header.php");` line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `session_start()` *before all other lines on very top*:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("header.php");
```

Also, don't `echo` or `print` or output anything on screen before header is sent.

Make sure that you don't use `session_start()` twice for example in your include files otherwise you will receive the same message.

---

[More Information on `session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have `session_start()` before anything, including HTML, on your web page. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Session start has to be the VERY FIRST thing to be seen/echoed/printed/anything.

```
<?php
session_start();

include("header.php");
```

will work, but even

```
 <?php
session_start();

include("header.php");
```

(note the extra space) won't.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

If you want to have the HTML tags in your code as well, the place has to be before them, too. Also, if you use UTF-8, even the BOM might be a problem, so if this won't solve then check that as well.